# Axios hangs when making GET request to specific webservice

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I'm trying to build a web scraping service that gets some data for use in my application.  I'm using NodeJS with Axios.  The problem is, I'm having some particular difficulty with one webservice and I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong.  The problem I'm having is that the webservice seems to never return any data to my application and the request just hangs.  I've used Axios-Curlirize to debug the issue by getting the cURL command and using that same command both in Terminal and in Postman, and in both cases the request returns almost instantly.  My request is not in a loop so I don't think I'm getting hit with anti-DDoS protection, and the exact same method I'm using works fine with other APIs I've tried to use.  Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?  Here's my code snippet, although it's fairly standard:

```
return await axios.get(url, { headers: headers})
            .then(() => {
                console.log("done")
            })
            .catch(err => failed(err));
```

Neither the console.log nor the function `failed` ever get called, I've put breakpoints there to check that; the contents of the function `failed` are not relevant because that function is never called.  I've tried on Node 14.7.0 and on Node 12.18.3LTS and it didn't work on either version.

Here's the cURL request from Axios-Curlirize:

```
curl -X GET -H "accept-language:en-CA,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" -H "dnt:1" -H "referer:https://www.google.com" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests:1" -H "user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36" -H "cookie-control:no-cache" -H "cache-control:max-age=0" -H "pragma:no-cache" "https://www.famousfootwear.com/stores/product/LocateCartAndNewVariantNearby?zipCode=98662&radius=25&variantToAdd=70094-110-07"
```

This cURL command works fine in terminal and in Postman but not in my application.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  The remote website only supports HTTP/2 and Axios only supports HTTP1.1.  Guess I gotta find another solution other than Axios.